# find matching sequence from crunch output and print in terminal

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

I want to pipe output of crunch 3 3 ALPHA and filter out and print all the possibilities that are odd letters or odd even odd OR even even odd letters

if crunch creates 3 3 alpha

eee
ebs
ccc
cbe
ace
add
cae

FROM THIS sequence i want to filter all the combinations of odd letters and print on screen OR

combination of odd even odd letters OR even even odd

"acegikmoqsuwy= odd"

"bdfhjlnprtvxz= even"

so for odd even odd i type in ubuntu terminal

crunch 3 3 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | grep -ioE '[acegikmoqsuwy]{3}' | grep -ioE '[bdfhjlnprtvxz]{3}' |  grep -ioE '[acegikmoqsuwy]{3}'

abc

adc

cbg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `grep`

```
$ grep -ioE '[acegikmoqsuwy]{3}' words
```

for testing, create a words file

```
$ echo {a..f}{a..f}{a,b} | tr ' ' '\n' > words
$ wc -l words
72 words

$ grep -ioE '[acegikmoqsuwy]{3}' words
aaa
aca
aea
caa
cca
cea
eaa
eca
eea
```

Comment: i tried this it works well but it only gives odd odd odd combinations from acegikmoqsuwy =3  suppose if i want odd even odd       [eg: acb, add, abd] to filter out                                            crunch 5 5 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | grep -ioE '[acegikmoqsuwy][bdfhjlnprtvxz]{5}'

Comment: well, you only asked about "odd odd odd".

Comment: yes thanks for your help.....i will try to edit the question....or ask a new one

Comment: No need.  For even take the complement of the charset and use as `grep .. [ac..][bd..][ac...]'  which will be "odd even odd"